# phpstorm french characters formating issue

Tags: html, phpstorm

I'm using PHPstorm 6.

When i try to format my code which contains french characters, i got a issue like you see on the pictures.

NB : i got this just when i put my text into a tag like :

```
<span>génie Informatique</span>
```

**So before formatting i was this :**

[image: so before formatting i was this]

**And after formatting i got this**

[image: And after formatting i got this]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of file is that -- HTML?

In any case: you do have light green background between the tags. This suggests that you have **another language injected** between those tags (Language Injection functionality), which may use completely different formatting rules (not HTML -- e.g. JavaScript or whatever you may have injected there).

**Possible solution:**
Place cursor somewhere between such tags, <kbd>Alt+Enter</kbd> (or click on light bulb icon) and use "Uninject Language" option.

**Alternatively:** `Settings | Language Injections` -- find and disable (or even delete) offending entry there (will be "global" or "project" type in last column).